# If key not in JSON then set value to null and insert into dataframe

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to get a value from a key in a JSON string and then insert that data into a dataframe.
But sometimes the column might appear in the structure or not, so if the key do not exist it gives me a error like `'KeyError': 'Company_Name_Abb'`.

So if I get this error, the data will not be inserted to the dataframe and will `pass` to the next contract, but that's not what I want. If some key doesn't exist, I'd like to set a **Null** value to it, so it can be inserted normally to a dataframe.

So if you notice in the JSON string below, I didn't get the **Company_Name_Abb** key .

```
{
  "success": "true",
  "code": 200,
  "messages": null,
  "response": {
    "templateType": "",
    "metadata": {
      "AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS": "0",
      "Reminder_date": "",
      "Monetary_Type": "",
      "Legal_Entity": "Test Inc.",
      "BIZ_DEV_CONTACT": "Goofy",
      "Business_Owner": "Minnie Mouse",
      "Contract_Status": "Active",
      "Cond_exp_terms": "",
      "Contract_Category": "General",
      "Contract_Term_Period_UoM": "Years",
      "Customer_ID_Intel": "",
      "Expiry_Date_words": "June 08, 2024",
      "Royalty_Max_Value": "",
      "TIMEZONE": "US/Pacific - (GMT-8:00)",
      "Audit_Section_Num": "",
      "Same_as_Contract_Signed_Date": "Enter Date",
      "CNDA_Number": "12345",
      "Contract_Title": "'TEST AGREEMENT FOR API No 2",
      "ConfidentialContract": "No",
      "Heirarchy_Status": "Master Agreement",
      "RSNDA_Number": "",
      "Contract_Signed_On_date": 1623263400000,
      "Termination_Section_Num": "",
      "Region": "N.A.",
      "Contract_Expiration_Date": 1717785000000,
      "Historical_Audit_Date": "",
      "RSNDA_Date": "",
      "PCM_Contact": "",
      "License_Technology": "",
      "PCM_Obligation": "No",
      "MILES_SUMM": "",
      "Effective_Date_words": "June 09, 2021",
      "Amendments": [],
      "Contract_Effective_Date": 1623177000000,
      "Folder": "Default",
      "RUNDA_Date": "",
      "Contract_Owner": "test@test.com",
      "Licensed_Tech_Name": "",
      "Payment_Terms": "",
      "SUBLICENSE": "Test",
      "AUTO_RENEW": "Fixed",
      "ATTORNEY_NOTES": "",
      "Vendor_ID_Intel": "",
      "Attorney_Owner": "",
      "Monetary_Num": "",
      "RUNDA_Number": "",
      "Notes": "",
      "Contract_Desc": "This is a test",
      "ContractualDoc": [],
      "Contract_Renewal_Date": "",
      "Monetary_Sec_Num": "",
      "SearchableContract": "Yes",
      "AUTO_RENEWAL_MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_RENEWALS": "0",
      "AUTO_RENEWAL_NOTICE_DAYS": "0",
      "Intel_Product_Family": "",
      "CNDA_Date": 1623177000000,
      "DEV_PARTNER": "",
      "Contract_Term": "3"
    },
    "contractNumber": "INTEL29017",
    "supportingDocuments": [],
    "statusCode": "",
  },
  "responseMap": null
}
```

> ***In the example below I just created two variables, but I'm getting all
> of the keys from the JSON. And also the JSON above is just one
> example, since the Foor Loop retrieves many JSON string as the one
> above.***

How I'm getting the values (**JSON.text I'm retrieving from a API**):

```
for element in jsoncontracts['response']['rows']:
    try:  
        jsoncontractsdetails = json.loads(JSON.text)
        
        Auto_Renewal_Period_Months, Company_Name_Abb = jsoncontractsdetails['response']['metadata']['AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS'], jsoncontractsdetails['response']['metadata']['Company_Name_Abb']

        df_contractnumberdetails = pd.DataFrame([[Auto_Renewal_Period_Months, Company_Name_Abb]], columns=['AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS', 'Company_Name_Abb'], index=None)

    except Exception as e:
        print('ContractNumberError: ' + contract)
        print(e)            
        pass
```

I already tried to Except KeyError and was able to assigned a value to it's key, but I couldn't insert to a dataframe because it was passing to the next contract in the loop.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use `defaultdict` function from `collections` module, but after I try to access the key from the function I still get `KeyError: 'Company_Name_Abb'`.

```
jsoncontractsdetails = defaultdict(lambda: -1, jsoncontractsdetails)
Company_Name_Abb = jsoncontractsdetails['response']['metadata']['Company_Name_Abb']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

- First, on the more fancy side is to use [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) library and define JSON object schema you expect. You can set both required and optional fields, potentially with default values.
- Second, even more fancy, is to use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and [dataclasses-json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/) library for even more convenient access. I would call this way the most preferable in the long term since you have a really convenient data structure to work with.
- Lastly, the quickest way would be to use `get()` (for getting values) or `setdefault()` (for setting values to the nested dictionaries which might not exist) dict methods. For example, you can access one of your fields as `jsoncontractsdetails.get('response', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS', None)`. This method quickly gets messy, but works great for one-offs or in small quantities :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. How the `setdefault()` would work in this occasion? Would I need to `setdefault` for each key or is there any way to set for all keys at once?

Comment: `jsoncontractsdetails.get('response', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS', None)` worked! But it I use for all columns from the JSON, I would have to write this 60x or is there any faster aproach for this solution?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus, `mydict.setdefault(key, value)` sets `mydict[key]` to `value` if the key doesn't exist and returns `mydict[key]`, so you can chain them.

Answer (score 0):

pandas can handle dictionaries, you could feed the rows to `pd.DataFrame` and then select only the columns you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([m['response']['metadata'] for m in jsoncontracts['response']['rows']])
```

if you want to select the columns beforehand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
           k:v for k,v in m['response']['metadata'].items() 
          if k in ('AUTO_RENEWAL_PERIOD_MONTHS', 'Company_Name_Abb')
        } 
        for m in jsoncontracts['response']['rows']
    ]
)
```

Comment: if `k not in` columns we have the value as None as "standard"?

Comment: as long as it is not `None` for one row, it will show as `None` for all the missing ones